# Securing Elmah RSS Feeds in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, security, rss, elmah

I followed the answer to this question [Securing Elmah in ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245364/securing-elmah-in-asp-net-website) to restrict access to the elmah handler. However, it seems that adding an RSS feed to Outlook for the URL elmah.axd/rss or elmah.axd/digestrss bypasses the authentication. What's the point of securing the handler if someone can guess the RSS URL and subscribe to a feed of the error log?

Comment: Have you solved this yet? If not, please post the URL Path to the file you want to secure (you don't have to give the complete public URL - I just need the relative path) and we'll go from there. It should be relatively easy to secure...

Answer (score 8):

I secure mine in the web.config with a role:

```
<location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="SUPER_DUPER_ADMIN"/> 
            <deny users="*"/> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: what's your opinion about http://geeks.ms/lruiz/2014/07/21/asp-net-revisa-la-configuracin-de-elmah-en-produccin ? security issues ?