# How secure Elmah?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, elmah

I am wondering how to actually secure elmah in my situation. I know you can disable remote connections(what I done) but how about for me I still want to be able to connect to it remotely just not anyone else.

Usually if I wanted to look at elmah errors I would just load up the site on local host with my live db in my web.config so I could access my elmah errors. For various reasons I cannot do this time around.

SO I know you can use asp.net authentication but I am unsure how that would work. Do I have to hardcode my user name in the web.config?

Or does it make it's login form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Securing Elmah in ASP.NET website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245364/securing-elmah-in-asp-net-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question:

[Securing Elmah in ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245364/securing-elmah-in-asp-net-website)

You can hard code your username in the web.config if you want, but if you have forms authentication setup against a database backend, you can use that too without having your username in the web.config