# Secure elmah directory gets 404?

Tags: iis, elmah

I've setup ELMAH on a asp.net mvc 3 site with the correct configuration detailed on another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245364/securing-elmah-in-asp-net-website).  Everything works great on my local virtual dev IIS server but when I deploy to an IIS server when I try to go to /Admin/Elmah.axd I get the standard IIS "404 - File or directory not found.".  Is there an IIS setting I'm missing?

```
  <location path="admin">
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got to add the httphandler to the System.Webserver part of the web.config so that IIS routes it:

```
<system.webServer>   
  <handlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="admin/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" name="Elmah"/>
  </handlers> 
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by installing the asp.net mvc elmah controller.   You can find it [here](http://www.beletsky.net/2011/08/elmah-mvc-controller-released-on-nuget.html).